# how to stop the page from redirecting to signin in my angular app

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to handle the status code 401 in my reset password controller but it is automatically redirecting to signin page which is defined in interceptor. this is my piece of code of both section.

```
 else if(error.status === 401){
  //   console.log("1111")
  // $location.path("/activate/:activationCode");

 // console.log($location.path())


//if($location.path=="/signin")


  $translate('UNAUTHORIZED_ACT').then(function(translation){
      self.alert ={
          type: 'danger',
          msg: translation
      };  setAlert(self.alert);
      $location.path("/activate/:activationCode");

    })
  console.log($location.path())

 //  if($location.path=="/signin")
   {
    $location.path("resetPassword/:resetToken");
    console.log("resetpswdcase")
    $translate('PSWD_RESET_TOKEN_MISSING').then(function(translation){
      self.alert ={
          type: 'danger',
          msg: translation
      };  setAlert(self.alert);

    })

  }

 }


if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                if($rootScope.isAuthenticated){
                    $translate('UNAUTHORIZED').then(function(translation){
                        Logger.logUnauthorizedRouteError();
                    })
                } else {
                    $location.path('/signin');
                }

           }
```

so, how can i stop the page from redirection in my controller with or without touching the interceptor?